# Retreive Gridpanel text from header and cell

Tags: extjs

I'm showing a Toast message when someone clicks at a specific cell from a gridpanel, and I'm retreiving the cell text and showing on a toast.

But I would like to show the information like this:

> Header Title: Cell text

My code:

```
  onItemClick: function(table, td, columnIndex, record, tr, rowIndex, e) {
    Ext.toast({
      timeout: 5000,
      html: td.innerText,
      width: 150,
      height: 20
    });
  }
```

When I print the innerText I receive the cell text only, I would like to show to my users the header title too, Is it possible to retreive this information by using the data received on parameters too? if not, how can I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cellclick listener inside grid as follows:

```
cellclick:function ( grid , td , cellIndex , record , tr , rowIndex , e , eOpts )
```

Here you will get table (as you get in itemclick of yours) and also one which is cellindex, i.e on which cell user has clicked.

Now you can get header as:

```
grid.panel.columns[cellIndex-1].text
```

You can use this inside your toast in whichever way you want to display. Also with

```
grid.panel.columns[cellIndex-1]
```

You can get the column clicked, so you can get whatever you need from that column. Happy Learning :)

Comment: My cellindex is returning 0 everytime, how can I fix that?

Comment: You have tried selecting different cells from different rows? Because it worked on my side and showing different cell indexes for that.